# Find biggest tables where pk is int (not bigint)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to find the tables with the most number of rows and exclude tables with bigint primary keys.

The query below runs very fast and seems to work, but how can I modify it to filter out the bigint tables? I could perhaps ignore row_counts that are larger than MAX_INT, but that does not work if a table is bigint but does not have a lot of rows yet.

```sql
SELECT      SCHEMA_NAME(O.schema_id) + '.' +
        O.Name As [Schema.TableName], SUM(P.rows) AS 'Total_RowCount'
FROM        sys.objects O
INNER JOIN sys.partitions P ON O.object_id = P.object_id
WHERE     O.type = 'U'
        AND P.index_id<2  
GROUP BY    O.schema_id, O.Name
order by Total_RowCount desc
```

Comment: This lists all columns with datatype bigint `select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where DATA_TYPE = 'bigint'`

Comment: The OP is probably better off using the other `sys` objects, as they are already using the `sys` objects. Also that would just omit a table where *any* column is a `bigint`, not the primary key, @Nick.McDermaid .

Comment: Correct. If I had a complete solution (which I rarely do) I would post as an answer. Yes it makes sense to consistently stick with either old school (sys) or modern (information schema) API's

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid `sys` is more modern for SQL Server, not `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`... The latter omits a lot of informations about the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `NOT EXISTS` in the `WHERE` and do a lateral join to the `sys.types` object for the primary key column(s). I *assume* if a PK is made of multiple columns, and one of them is a `bigint` you want to omit it:

```sql
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) + '.' + o.name AS [Schema.TableName],
       SUM(p.rows) AS Total_RowCount
FROM sys.objects o
     INNER JOIN sys.partitions p ON o.object_id = p.object_id
WHERE o.type = 'U'
  AND p.index_id < 2
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM sys.indexes i 
                       JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON o.object_id = ic.object_id
                                                AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
                       JOIN sys.columns c ON o.object_id = c.object_id
                                         AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
                       JOIN sys.types ct ON c.system_type_id = ct.system_type_id
                  WHERE o.object_id = i.object_id
                    AND i.is_primary_key = 1
                    AND ct.[name] = 'bigint')
GROUP BY o.schema_id,
         o.name
ORDER BY Total_RowCount DESC;
```